# C# TcpClient giving ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a very basic socket chat room (both server/client). I am having trouble with ObjectDisposedException error in my server. Each time a client connects, it will create a new thread to deal with this client (Yes I know this could be problematic for large numbers of clients, but I would only have a maximum of 10). This thread will then loop, and each time it does will read the NetworkStream that is connected to the client, echo it back to the clients, and then loop. Here is the code:

```
while (true)
{
    buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

    //Read incoming data
    int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

    string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    if (dataReceived == "CONSOLE::close") //if client tells server it is closing, remove client from clients list
    {
        clients.Remove(client);
        client.Close();
        break;
    }
    else //send data to all clients
    {
        byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataReceived);

        foreach (TcpClient b in clients)
        {
            NetworkStream x = b.GetStream();
            x.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Where client is the current client connection, and clients is a list of all current clients connected.

I am getting the error in the first line inside of the while loop `buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];` More details about the error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.
```

But the object has not been disposed of by me? Also note I am using multiple threads so not sure if this would affect it. Could someone give me a better understanding of why this error is occuring? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Here is the snippet of code before the while loop (same method):

```
byte[] buffer;

//Client has connected
client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
clients.Add(client);

//Create new thread for listening
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ClientListener));
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();

AppendTextBox("Client has connected" + Environment.NewLine);

//Create network stream to get incoming data
NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
```

And the method is called when a button is clicked.

```
localIP = IPAddress.Parse(SERVER_IP);
listener = new TcpListener(localIP, PORT);
listener.Start();

//Create new thread on which the server listens for clients
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ClientListener));
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

**SOLUTION:**
I was stupid and did not realize that initializing the `client` outside of the local method made it accessible by all threads. So that when one thread closed the `client` it closed them all. Thanks to Karolis.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than just part of the code.

Comment: @JonSkeet Im not sure what else would help in this situation, as nothing else has to do with the client / server side communication.

Comment: Well there's the calling code to start with... fundamentally, if you don't give us enough information to reproduce it, we're not going to be able to help you. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and bear in mind that the sooner you accept the advice for how to improve your question, the sooner you'll get an answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Pretty close to be first ever to reach 1 m rep. Congratulations! @LachlanMather On the question. From given code I cannot locate the issue. Could it be that you run more than one `while` loops?

Comment: @Karolis There are multiple threads possibly running while loops (sometimes they are waiting idly, sometimes looping) could this be an issue?

Comment: @LachlanMather Consider scenario - one thread enters else statement and calls `client.Close();` other thread tries to access client which is already disposed. So if you share same client across the threads that is most likely the issue.

Comment: Wouldn't the threads use their own version of `client` though? Their own local version of `client`?

Comment: @LachlanMather I do not see where you create client. :)

Comment: `TcpClient client;` (excuse me here but I do not know how to describe it) is a part of the code which is not inside a method.

Comment: @Karolis Oh. I realised my mistake. Having the initailization of the client outside of the local method made it accessible by all threads... stupid me. Thank you for your time helping me.

Comment: @LachlanMather everyone here is a student, no need to be so harsh on yourself. Glad that you've managed to solve the issue.

Comment: Would u mind to provide correct solution please?